# Multi-line string as part of sequence

Tags: syntax, yaml

I can't figure out how to use a multi-line string as part of a yaml sequence:

```
foo:
  - bar
  - bar2
  - > super duper long
 string that I would like
 to have on multiple lines
  - Another item
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If you want to use a folded scalar:

```
foo:
  - bar
  - bar2
  - >
     super duper long
     string that I would like
     to have on multiple lines
  - Another item
```

Note that there may not be content on the line of the folded scalar's header (the line with the `>`).

Alternatively, you can just use a plain scalar:

```
foo:
  - bar
  - bar2
  - super duper long
    string that I would like
    to have on multiple lines
  - Another item
```

Comment: W̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶l̶a̶i̶n̶ ̶s̶c̶a̶l̶a̶r̶ ̶f̶o̶l̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶l̶i̶n̶e̶?̶ Yes it will, the main difference is that there won't be a newline at the end.

Comment: Yes. If you want the folded scalar not to include the trailing newline, use `>-` instead of `>`.

Comment: I'd like to point out that in this case the indentation is really picky (for good reasons).

Comment: Well you need more indentation than the parent element (in this case, the list items starting with `-`). One space more suffices in both cases. In a folded scalar, continuing lines may not be lesser indented than the first content line. This restriction does not apply to a multiline plain scalar, so it is allowed for the line `string that I would like` to be one space lesser indented than the previous one in the second code block.

Comment: So having `>-` is the same as plain scalar?

Comment: @TriNguyen Not quite. `>-` disables all special characters inside the block, so you can't have a comment with `#` and `:` will not end your scalar; you can start your scalar with `'` or `"` and so on.

Comment: use `- |` if you want `\n`