# Multi-line in a sequence in YAML

Tags: syntax, yaml

I would like to have multiple lines in a sequence in YAML. This is how I do it, but I have issues with parsing it in python:

```
Element: |
   - multiple lines
     come here
```

Doing it this way, when I parse it with Python, I still see the `-` in the parsed data. It seems that YAML does not understand this is a list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-line string as part of sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46696057/multi-line-string-as-part-of-sequence)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your input is not a list, YAML only knows about mappings (constructed as a Python `dict` and sequences (constructed as a Python `list`).

Normally `-` is the block sequence entry indicator, But since you start a block style literal on the first line as the value for the key `Element`, because of the `|`, everything following it that is indented is part of this scalar (constructed as a Python string).

What you want to do is bring the indicator outside of the literal scalar:

```
Element: 
- |
  multiple lines
  come here
```

If you load that in Python in a variable `data` then `data['Element'][0]` will be the string `'multiple lines\ncome here\n'`. That is: every newline in your literal scalar will be a newline in your string, and there will be a single final newline on that string independent of how many empty lines follow (this is clipping). If you want the end to have no newline, then use `|-` (stripping), and if you want all newlines until outdenting then use `|+` (keeping). Those additions to the `|` are called [chomping indicators](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2794534).

If you have the above in a file called `input.yaml`:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

input = Path('input.yaml')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
data = yaml.load(input)
print(f'{data["Element"][0]!r}')  # print the representation, so you can see where the newlines are
```

which gives:

```
'multiple lines\ncome here\n'
```

Comment: Thanks Anthon. However, I am getting the following error: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a simple key
could not find expected ':'. I am using yaml instead of ruamel.yaml. Can this be the issue?

Comment: I can load the above code without any problem in PyYAML (assuming that is what you mean by "using yaml"). You're probably doing something wrong, but since you did not include actual code in your question, you make it unnecessary difficult to figure out what you are actually doing wrong.

Comment: The issue was that my indentation started at '-' rather than 'I'. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Use this syntax (for the `yaml` Python package, at least)

```
stuff:
  - 'this is a multiline
  string'
```

In other words quote the string and unindent its continuation.

Comment: Thanks for your repspose. If I would also like to break the line right when I have the newline, similar to the functionality provided by "|" in YAML, shall I use '\n' inside the quotation, or is there a better technique?

Comment: Just add a true newline after the opening quotation

Comment: I mean between multiline and string above, if I just press enter like how you described it above, the python library does not put \n there.

Comment: *That is not a multiline string*. That multiline scalar gets loaded as a Python string without any newlines. Adding a newline after the opening quotation will not help, because single newlines within a single quoted scalar are represented as a single space. Unindenting the continuation has no effect on the representation.